# jQuery GET Not Working

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, get

To preface this, let me says that I'm.. 'newish' to jQuery. I have the concept and most of the usage downpat, but I'm not perfect with all these brackets and functions yet.

Hence why I'm probably making an amateur mistake here. I am using the following code to submit some data, move to the next section of the page and then **attempting** to load new content into the drop down menu in the next section:

```
    $('#submit').click(function() {

    var nam = $('#name').val();
    var par = $("#parentCategory").val();
    var dat = $("#catDate").val();

    $.post("<?php echo site_url('admin/add_gallery'); ?>", {name: nam, parent: par, cat_date: dat}, function() {
        if (par != 'undefined')
        {
            $('#next_tab').click()
        }
        else
        {
            $("#gallery").click(),
            $("#name").val('')
        }
    });

    $.get("http://www.example.com/admin/get_galleries", function(gals)
    { // Get the Contents of Drop Down Gallery Select
        $("#galleryChoose").html(gals);
    }); 

    alert('yop');       

});
```

Unfortunately it's not working. The POST works great, but the #galleryChoose (which is a

tag) never gets filled with the new content.

The URL I am calling with GET (usually a URL to my testing site, I changed it for example purposes) produces a dropdown with all the latest elements in it, but referencing it with GET doesn't seem to work. Do I have to return it for GET in some specific way? I'm just using `return $variable` right now, where the $variable has all the HTML.

Any help would be much appreciated. Been a long night struggling with this one.

UPDATE: this is the code that I reference with the URL (It's CodeIgniter, so this is in my Controller):

```
    function get_galleries()
{
    $galleries = $this->find->all_items('galleries');
    $return = '<label>Choose the Gallery:</label> <br />';
    $return .= '<select id="galleryParent" name="galleryParent">';
    foreach ($galleries as $gals)
    {
        $return .= '<option id="'.$gals->gal_name.'" value="'.$gals->gal_id.'">'.$gals->gal_name.'</option>';
    }
    $return .= '</select>';   

    echo $return;     
}
```

Comment: Not sure it solves your problem, but you've got some line ending issues. `$("gallery").click(),` should end in a semicolon, not a comma. You also have two other unterminated statements. With JavaScript's infamous implicit semicolons, you should always add all semicolons yourself, rather than leaving the decision to the JS interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that what you want to do is update some data via `$.post` then get the updated data using get? In that case you have an issue since `$.post` and `$.get` is asynchronous, meaning that the browser wont wait for it to finish before proceeding in the script.

What this means is that your script will call `$.post` and `$.get` almost simultaneously, instead, try placing your get inside the callback for `$.post` like so:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {

    var nam = $('#name').val();
    var par = $("#parentCategory").val();
    var dat = $("#catDate").val();

    $.post("<?php echo site_url('admin/add_gallery'); ?>", {name: nam, parent: par, cat_date: dat}, function() {
        if (par != 'undefined')
        {
            $('#next_tab').click()
        }
        else
        {
            $("#gallery").click(),
            $("#name").val('')
        }
        $.get("http://www.example.com/admin/get_galleries", function(gals)
        { // Get the Contents of Drop Down Gallery Select
            $("#galleryChoose").html(gals);
        }); 
    });



    alert('yop');       

});
```

Comment: I thnk that's it. I should have seen that. +1

Comment: I will definitely look into this, as that makes sense. I believe I did try that though, however it just made things flicker and look like the page was reloading, but didn't work. I will double check it all and try to implement it properly.

Comment: You should also check out Firebug (http://www.getfirebug.com) and see if the output you get from http://www.example.com/admin/get_galleries is the output you expect there to be. (Or, you know, just go to the address)

Comment: As I noted on D Hoerster's answer, I used Firebug extensively and checked the URL, it sends back HTML exactly what I want.

Comment: Didn't work, but I'm sure you were right. Substituted the completely unnecessary GET for a much simpler LOAD command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP guy, but does removing the leading `/` in your directory string (`/admin/get_galleries`) fix it?  You'd append `admin/get_galleries` instead, since your link variable already has the trailing `/`.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I updated the code for that. In my actual situation, I'm not using the link variable, I just pass in the full URL.

Comment: Is the GET going to the same domain as the page that it's hosted on?  I'm assuming it is, but thought I'd ask.

Comment: Also, if you replace the `$("#gallery...").html(gals)` call with an `alert(gals)`, what do you get?  Have you monitored the call with Fiddler or Firebug -- anything coming back from the server?

Comment: a) The server is the same, so the Same Domain Policy doesn't apply. b) I have tried alerting it, and I get absolutely nothing back. I used firebug and even tried to console.log the data, but I never get a response.

Comment: Do you know that it's getting processed on the server side - debugging/tracing/output-to-text-file/etc.?  Sorry for the obvious questions.

Comment: have you tried navigating the get url from the browser directly?

try to navigate this on the browser "http://www.example.com/admin/get_galleries" then view the source of when it's done. Inspect if there is a result, or the results are valid.

Comment: it would also be helpful if we can have a glance at the php code returning the results.

Comment: Sorry for the delays. The answer is yes, I have navigated directly to the URL and it outputs the exact HTML that I want. (it just shows the HTML). I have tested various outputs from it, but I'm here because it never seems to output anything.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter comes with $_GET disabled by default. You have to enable it in order to use it. Take a look here: [CodeIgniter User Guide, Security](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/security.html)

Comment: Yeah, but it works perfectly fine in another section of my site where I get the cart contents using almost identical syntax.

Comment: Maybe you are using a bad route.

Make sure you are using <?= site_url('controller/method'); ?> along your requests.

I think that the problem is caused by jQuery, it can't make cross domain calls(even between 'http://localhost' and 'http://127.0.0.1'). If you want to do that you need to use JSON.

Hope it helps.. I had similar problem.